# Generate tableau histogram based on count of aggregated measure

Tags: tableau-api

My input data is like below

```
scenario,pnl
------------
1,5
2,0
3,12
4,0
5,0
6,14
```

I need to create a histogram of frequencies. So i created bins and all is good.

```
bin, count(pnl)
---------------
0-4,3
5-9,1
10-14,2
```

Now as a next step, my input data is segregated based on account like below

```
scenario,pnl,acc
------------
1,3,a
1,2,b
2,0,c
3,8,d
3,3,d
3,1,d
4,0,e
4,0,e
5,0,f
6,14,g
```

Now i need the same histogram as before, so i need to group on the scenario, sum up PnLs and then take the count on the summed up pnls to find the right bins. I am stuck at how do i do the grouping on scenario before i do the histogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Level of Detail Expressions](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_calculatedfields_lod_overview.html).

Create a calculated field for SUM `pnl` measure, as follows:

```
{FIXED [Scenario]: SUM([pnl])}
```

This calculates a fixed sum of `pnl` for each scenario. With this measure, create the bins for your histogram, and count the elements of this field.